# Why can I not cast my filter as listboxfilter in ironpython?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

The result of my .AsListBoxFilter is None, as per the error message AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetValues'. I see no reason why this would fail, since my data is categorical.

```
for vis in visuals:
    dt = Document.Data.Tables["abcddata"]
    filter = Document.FilteringSchemes.DefaultFilteringSchemeReference[dt]["JNJ_BATCH_ID"]
    lb = filter.As[ListBoxFilter]()
    tofilter = ["61568283", "61568290"]
    lb.SetValues(tofilter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few extra statements needed, and indeed the function *SetValues* does not exist. I replaced it with *SetSelection*. You need to set *IncludeAllValues* to False before, otherwise it does not select.

I removed the loop through the visuals as setting the filter did not use visuals.

To make answering easier, please include the imports and variable settings in a sample script. This worked for me (with my sample data):

```
import Spotfire.Dxp.Data
import Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import ListBoxFilter,FilterTypeIdentifiers

dt = Document.Data.Tables["abcddata"]
filter = Document.FilteringSchemes.DefaultFilteringSchemeReference[dt]["JNJ_BATCH_ID"]
filter.TypeId = FilterTypeIdentifiers.ListBoxFilter
lb = filter.As[ListBoxFilter]()
tofilter = ["61568283", "61568290"]
lb.IncludeAllValues=False
lb.SetSelection(tofilter)
```

Comment: Ah that is what is the TypeId is for. Thank you!